# Getting an error in smart contract Fundme, The error is "VM execution error. Reverted to 0x"

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

```
//  SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.6.6 <0.9.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract FundMe {
     mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;

   function fund() public payable {
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;

   }

   function getVersion() public view returns (uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
        return priceFeed.version();
   }

   function getPrice() public view returns (uint256){
       AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
       priceFeed.latestRoundData();
   }
}
```

Comment: On what network is your contract deployed (Remix VM emulator, Ropsten, BSC Mainnet, etc)? ... When does the error occurs? While deploying the contract? While executing a specific function (which one)? Please share repro steps.

Comment: The contract is deployed in kovan Testnet

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.
I googled `0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e` and got this website:

https://docs.chain.link/docs/ethereum-addresses/

So the contract address that you are passing is deployed on Rinkeby test network. connect to Rinkeby account on metamask wallet, chooce injected web3 in remix environment:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for figuring the issue. Now its resolve